# Avoid iteration over rows for computation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
County  date    available_wheat usage rate (%)  consumption
A   1/2/2021    100.00          3   
A   1/3/2021                    3   
A   1/4/2021                    2   
A   1/5/2021                    5   
A   1/6/2021                    1   
A   1/7/2021                    2   
A   1/8/2021                    5   
A   1/9/2021                    6   
A   1/10/2021                   7   
A   1/11/2021                   8   
A   1/12/2021                   1   
A   1/13/2021                   2
```

Above is my dataframe, I need to fill in the available in the columns. Available need to be reduced by usage rate (%), I am able to do using iterrows (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).

My dataframe is quite big compared to what is displayed so the question is: is it possible to vectorize the calculation using either lambda or something else?

Expected output:

```
County  date    available_wheat usage rate (%)  consumption
A   1/2/2021    100.00             3              3.00
A   1/3/2021    97.00              3              2.91
A   1/4/2021    94.09              2              1.88
A   1/5/2021    92.21              5              4.61
A   1/6/2021    87.60              1              0.88
A   1/7/2021    86.72              2              1.73
A   1/8/2021    84.99              5              4.25
A   1/9/2021    80.74              6              4.84
A   1/10/2021   75.89              7              5.31
A   1/11/2021   70.58              8              5.65
A   1/12/2021   64.93              1              0.65
A   1/13/2021   64.29              2              1.29
```

Comment: could you turn the columns into list, iterate through those and assign back to the empty columns?

Comment: @EmiOB that wouldn't address well the "*Avoid iteration*" part of the question :p

Comment: @mozway was thinking under then 'something else' part :p and interpreted that as avoiding iterating over the dataframe, which is bad

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a shifted [`cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) of your usage rate:

```
factor = df['usage rate (%)'].shift(fill_value=0).rsub(100).div(100).cumprod()

df['available_wheat'] = df['available_wheat'].ffill().mul(factor)
df['consumption'] = df['usage rate (%)'].mul(df['available_wheat']).div(100)
```

*NB. if you have several counties and want to handle them independently, then perform all that within a `groupby`. Add `round(2)` to get 2 significant digits.*

output:

```
   County       date  available_wheat  usage rate (%)  consumption
0       A   1/2/2021       100.000000               3     3.000000
1       A   1/3/2021        97.000000               3     2.910000
2       A   1/4/2021        94.090000               2     1.881800
3       A   1/5/2021        92.208200               5     4.610410
4       A   1/6/2021        87.597790               1     0.875978
5       A   1/7/2021        86.721812               2     1.734436
6       A   1/8/2021        84.987376               5     4.249369
7       A   1/9/2021        80.738007               6     4.844280
8       A  1/10/2021        75.893727               7     5.312561
9       A  1/11/2021        70.581166               8     5.646493
10      A  1/12/2021        64.934673               1     0.649347
11      A  1/13/2021        64.285326               2     1.285707
```

##### grouped per County

Same logic in a `groupby`:

```
factor = (df.groupby('County')['usage rate (%)']
            .apply(lambda s: s.shift(fill_value=0).rsub(100).div(100).cumprod())
         )

df['available_wheat'] = df.groupby('County')['available_wheat'].ffill().mul(factor)
df['consumption'] = df['usage rate (%)'].mul(df['available_wheat']).div(100)
```

Comment: @Lata see update, in such case it's best to provide an example that demonstrates the expected output with at least 2 groups ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
dd1=df1["usage rate (%)"].div(100)
df1["available_wheat"]=dd1.rsub(1).cumprod().mul(100).shift(fill_value=100)
df1["consumption"]=df1.available_wheat.mul(dd1)
df1

out：

  County       date  available_wheat  usage rate (%)  consumption
0       A   1/2/2021           100.00               3         3.00
1       A   1/3/2021            97.00               3         2.91
2       A   1/4/2021            94.09               2         1.88
3       A   1/5/2021            92.21               5         4.61
4       A   1/6/2021            87.60               1         0.88
5       A   1/7/2021            86.72               2         1.73
6       A   1/8/2021            84.99               5         4.25
7       A   1/9/2021            80.74               6         4.84
8       A  1/10/2021            75.90               7         5.31
9       A  1/11/2021            70.59               8         5.65
10      A  1/12/2021            64.94               1         0.65
11      A  1/13/2021            64.29               2         1.29
```